# What does 'CuArray only supports element types that are stored inline' mean in Julia using CuArrays?

Tags: julia, flux

I want to know why some codes work fine when using standard arrays but fail when using CuArrays.

For example, I have an array `time_idx` defined as:

```
1×32 CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}:
 0.71173  0.941251  0.571602  0.037198  0.212053  0.227296  0.457712  0.697708  0.788338  0.994031  0.228599  …  0.856314  0.830083  0.111376  0.0333812  0.722638  0.293733  0.114187  0.072304  0.275268
```

and a vector of CuArrays `vehicle_states`, each with a dim of 7*32:

```
3-element Vector{CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}:
 [0.49417984 0.11234676 … 0.107337356 0.72619927; 0.46416637 0.21656695 … 0.18117706 0.18970703; … ; 0.15575896 0.79976654 … 0.3788491 0.29301012; 0.97315633 0.8638843 … 0.5506643 0.30244973]
 [0.4448264 0.9205822 … 0.61369383 0.5310524; 0.75463957 0.29982162 … 0.13896087 0.09793778; … ; 0.60275537 0.39284942 … 0.2803427 0.7379274; 0.8305204 0.056631837 … 0.16771089 0.9385667]
 [0.78282833 0.594285 … 0.65157485 0.82812166; 0.28565544 0.021899216 … 0.7051293 0.48643407; … ; 0.18139555 0.44223073 … 0.9017556 0.3409817; 0.5128845 0.79966474 … 0.039010685 0.53230214]
```

I want to concatenate them using broadcast behavior but an error occurred (this is fine when using standard arrays):

```
vcat.(time_idx, vehicle_states) # CuArray only supports element types that are stored inline
```

But if I don't use broadcasting, it will work just fine:

```
[vcat(time_idx, vehicle_state) for vehicle_state in vehicle_states]
```

```
3-element Vector{CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}:
 [0.7117298 0.94125116 … 0.07230403 0.27526757; 0.49417984 0.11234676 … 0.107337356 0.72619927; … ; 0.15575896 0.79976654 … 0.3788491 0.29301012; 0.97315633 0.8638843 … 0.5506643 0.30244973]
 [0.7117298 0.94125116 … 0.07230403 0.27526757; 0.4448264 0.9205822 … 0.61369383 0.5310524; … ; 0.60275537 0.39284942 … 0.2803427 0.7379274; 0.8305204 0.056631837 … 0.16771089 0.9385667]
 [0.7117298 0.94125116 … 0.07230403 0.27526757; 0.78282833 0.594285 … 0.65157485 0.82812166; … ; 0.18139555 0.44223073 … 0.9017556 0.3409817; 0.5128845 0.79966474 … 0.039010685 0.53230214]
```

Why is that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you try to run:

```
vcat.(time_idx, vehicle_states)
```

it's probably trying to make the outer container `CuArray` instead of `Vector`, if you look at this variable's type:

```
3-element Vector{CUDA.CuArray{Float32, 2, CUDA.Mem.DeviceBuffer}}:
```

the outer type is just `Vector`, it's a `Vector` of `CuArray`. And more importantly, you cannot have a `CuArray` of `CuArray` because of the same reason outlined in the error message.

The error message is basically saying, each element inside the `CuArray` has to be `isbits` (that's the only way to store them in VRAM) but when you have a Vector of Vector, each element is a "pointer to a vector", that's not "just some bits", and thus not GPU compatible.